# Cannot run visio macro using python

Tags: python, vba, visio, pywin32, win32com

I'm trying to run a visio macro using python. I got this so far which doesn't work i get error: `AttributeError: <unknown>.Run` when calling doc.Application.Run

```
if os.path.exists("Drawing1.vsdm"):
    visio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
    visio.Visible = 1
    doc = visio.Documents.Open("Drawing1.vsdm")
    doc.Application.Run("Drawing1.vsdm!test.Read_text_File")
```

I have seen some examples where people are running excel macros this way

```
if os.path.exists("excelsheet.xlsm"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("excelsheet.xlsm"))
    xl.Application.Run("excelsheet.xlsm!modulename.macroname")
    xl.Application.Save() 
    xl.Application.Quit()
    del xl
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visio the Application object doesn't have a `Run` method, but there is an [`ExecuteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.document.executeline) method on Document.

So if your Visio document had a VBA procedure like this:

```vb
    Public Sub SayHello(ByVal name As String)
        MsgBox "Hello " & name & "!", vbOKOnly
    End Sub
```

then the following Python would work:

```py
doc.ExecuteLine('ThisDocument.SayHello "Bob"')
```

Comment: doc.ExecuteLine('ThisDocument.SayHello "Bob"')?

Can you please tell if i want to run the macro using ExecuteLine function how to do so ?